# problem with harvard referencing style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, harvard-style

I have to use Harvard referencing style for my essay, but there is a problem. In reference list it doesn't show the publisher and the address of the book. Also, could it write edition instead of edn.? Also, why it doesn't show (author's name, year) but it shows (author's name year)?

The .bib source is

```
@book{thri,
       author = {Thirlwal, A. P.},
       year = {2011},
       title = {Economics of development : theory and evidence},
       edition = {9th}
       publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
       address = {New York}
}
```

The main body of the essay has including citation

```
Firstly, despite the differences,  \cite{thri}. commodities’ \cite{thri}{p.71}; 

\citationstyle{dcu}

\bibliography{essay}
```

[image: sample]

My desidered reference would be,

> Thirwall, A. P. (2011). *Economics of development: theory and evidence, 9th ediiton*. New York: Palgrave Macmillan.

How can I add quotation's page?

Comment: From your code snippet it seems you doesn't actually use the `biblatex` package, so I removed that tag. Can you show a complete, minimal example, rather than just a snippet? Which `\bibliographystyle` are you using?

Comment: I'm using dcu style.

Comment: The problem with the `publisher` and `address` fields not being typeset is due solely to a syntax error in your bib file: the line `edition = {9th}` is not being terminated by a comma. When you run BibTeX, you *must* have been getting a warning/error message about a missing comma.

Answer (score 3):

Use a bibliographystyle that better suits your needs. Thousands are available.

`chicago.bst`:
[image: brianBibStyleChicago]

`apalike.bst`:
[image: brianBibstyleApalike]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{thri,
        author = {Thirlwal, A. P.},
        year = {2011},
        title = {Economics of development: theory and evidence},
        edition = {9th},
        publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
        address = {New York}
    }
    @article{ahu61,
        author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
        title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
        journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
        volume={8},
        year = {1961},
        pages = {175-191}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor \citep{ahu61} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
exports have been raised \citep[p.~42]{thri}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error was not caused by the bibliography style (`dcu`) being unsuitable. Instead, it was caused by a syntax error -- a missing comma to delimit a field -- in the bib file.

Comment: @Mico I know. There is the other issue of the abbreviated `edn` and the page number. I didn't explicitely explain anything, the question is very old and i couldn't decide wether just closing it or add a very trivial answer.

Comment: OK, I've retracted my "close" vote and posted an answer to show how the `dcu` bibliography file would have to be modified to show "edition" rather than "edn".

Answer (score 1):

What you want is almost the default of style `authoryear` with [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{thri,
        author = {Thirlwal, A. P.},
        year = {2011},
        title = {Economics of development: theory and evidence},
        edition = {9th},
        publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
        address = {New York}
    }
    @article{ahu61,
        author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
        title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
        journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
        volume={8},
        year = {1961},
        pages = {175-191}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor \parencite{ahu61} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
exports have been raised \parencite[42]{thri}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: standard authoryear]

To get the word "edition" at the end of the edition you could simply change the format of the field `edition`:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\addspace\biblstring{edition}}
```

[image: with text edition]

A better solution would be, to use an integer value `9` instead of the ordinal `9th` and use a extended field format similar to `biblatex`'s default:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{thri,
        author = {Thirlwal, A. P.},
        year = {2011},
        title = {Economics of development: theory and evidence},
        edition = {9},
        publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
        address = {New York}
    }
    @article{ahu61,
        author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
        title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
        journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
        volume={8},
        year = {1961},
        pages = {175-191}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\biblstring{edition}}
    {#1\isdot}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor \parencite{ahu61} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
exports have been raised \parencite[42]{thri}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See my comment under @JohannesB.'s answer: There's nothing wrong with the bibliography style. The cause of the error is much simpler: a missing comma at the end of a field...

Comment: @Mico Nevertheless, I would suggest `biblatex`.

Comment: The OP stated that he/she wants "edition", not "edn", to appear after "9th". Your proposed solution doesn't appear to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the missing `publisher` and `address` fields is caused by a simple syntax error -- a missing comma -- in your bib file: You need to terminate the line `edition = {9th}` with a comma.

If you want the citation call-out to show up as `(Thirlwal, 2011)` instead of as `(Thirlwal 2011)`, I suggest you (a) change from the `harvard` citation management package to the `natbib` citation management and (b) use `\citep` instead of `\cite` to generate the citation call-out.

If you need to change the edition label "edn" to "edition", I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `dcu` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file, and call the copy, say, `mydcu.bst`.
- Open the file `mydcu.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use for your tex files will do fine.
- In this file, find the function called `format.edition`. (It should start around line 312.) In this function, replace the two instances of "edn" with "edition".
- Save the file `mydcu.bst`, either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- In your main tex file change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{dcu}` to `\bibliographystyle{mydcu}`. Then re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{thri,
   author = {Thirlwal, A. P.},
   year = {2011},
   title = {Economics of Development: Theory and Evidence},
   edition = {9th},
   publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
   address = {New York}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard} % or: '\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}'
\bibliographystyle{mydcu}
\begin{document}
\cite{thri}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, that is a *session* of answer the unanswered. :-) Three answers in one hour to a question that is more than three years old :-)